# How do I insert an operator between the elements of a vector?

Tags: r, recursion, binary, operators

I would like to exploit the associativity of a binary operator by applying it to a vector of arbitary length. One can do that in Mathematica. I found a way to do it using recursive functions. Here is an example:

```
insert.binary.operator <- function(x, bin.op) {
  recur.op <- function(n) {
    if (n == 2) {
      return(bin.op(x[2], x[1]))
    } else {
    bin.op(x[n], recur.op(n-1))
    }
  }
  recur.op(length(x))
}
```

It works!

```
> insert.binary.operator(1:10, `+`)
[1] 55
```

My question is, is there something in the R language that does the same thing? If there is, it certainly would be faster and use less memory than the solution above.

Comment: In your example, `sum(1:10)` gives the same result as your recursive function.  So, if your operator is vectorised and (almost?) all are in R, simply apply it to your function.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: `Reduce("+",1:10)`?

Comment: The answer to the question is @NelsonGon's. `Reduce` can be applied to any associative operator, such as [matrix] multiplication.

Comment: @NelsonGon - Thanks. That is what I needed.